# How to change exported variable's value in a remote bash

Tags: server, bash, environment-variables, sshpass

I am working on some script that i will need to send variables from my local PC to a remote server, then i will need to change those values on the server within that script,

I am using the below testing script:

```
   #!/bin/bash
    export var=2
    sshpass -p PASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@xx.xx.xxx.xx 'bash -s' << EOF
    echo $var
    var=3
    echo $var
    x=4
    echo $x
    EOF
```

But the output for var for both echos is still "2", and x gives empty result, how to make changes or define new variable remotely?

Help please?

Comment: How do you plan to use those variables on the remote server? Do you need them to be available only for the ssh execution (once), or also for future login into the remote server?

Comment: No just for one time run within that script

Comment: Quote the heredoc marker if you want to protect variables from being expanded locally e.g. `bash << \EOF` or `bash << "EOF"`

Comment: @steeldriver, thank that made me able to define the variable remotely, but i lost my local variable's value!, the 1st echo printed empty result, 2nd and 3rd printed 3 and 4 as expected,

Comment: AFAIK you can't export variables across SSH in that way - what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Just a script that takes folders/ files names and other data from my local PC every time i need to run it, and perform sequence of operations on a remote server. Exporting to a remote server through ssh is working fine with me in such scripts, but this time the difference that i will need to define/ change variables on the remote server too, not only exporting,